# Java SLF4J warning when starting hive on WINDOWS 10

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, slf4j

I am trying to start HIVE 3.1.2 on Hadoop 3.3.0 on my windows 10 PC for training purpose (yes I know linux is better ;-) but someone has to do it anyway). I have the following error message

it looks related to how SLF4J works (I guess) but since I am not a java (or any other language) dev I have no clue how to fix it
For what it worth I do not have an IT background so be gentle and talk to me as if I was 10y/o

Could any one help (BTW it is running on java 8)

$ hive

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.

SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/zztop/hadoop/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.14.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/zztop/hadoop/hive/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/zztop/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.

SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]

WARNING: sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass is not supported. This will impact performance.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil

at org.apache.logging.log4j.status.StatusLogger.<clinit>(StatusLogger.java:71)

at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:60)

at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:45)

at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:46)

at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:30)

at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:281)

at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:301)

at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.<clinit>(RunJar.java:55)
```

Comment: Do you understand  the error messages?

Comment: My « understanding » is rather a deduction and googling... I understand Java do not know which file to pick as there are several between Hadoop and hive. Assuming my understanding is correct, how can I help Java to figure out which one to choose?

Comment: So, this isn't an error, and doesn't prevent Hive or Hadoop from actually working. You just might not get the correct logging output

Comment: Sorry Onecricketeer, missed this one. Hive is not even starting after firing up the error message. May be the Root cause is because hive is under the same directory as Hadoop .??. I mean Hadoop and Hadoop/hive

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is a misconfiguration of the logging framework, which it detects and complains about, including a link to http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings which explains the following:

> SLF4J API is designed to bind with one and only one underlying logging
> framework at a time. If more than one binding is present on the class
> path, SLF4J will emit a warning, listing the location of those
> bindings.
>
> When multiple bindings are available on the class path, select one and
> only one binding you wish to use, and remove the other bindings. For
> example, if you have both slf4j-simple-2.0.0-alpha0.jar and
> slf4j-nop-2.0.0-alpha0.jar on the class path and you wish to use the
> nop (no-operation) binding, then remove slf4j-simple-2.0.0-alpha0.jar
> from the class path.

It is not uncommon to see this problem, when combining multiple things together that bring their own logging backend.  The solution is to figure out why (the jars are listed) and only leave one binding.

Comment: Thanks Thorbjorn. I noticed there was 2 similar jars, one into hive path and the other one into the Hadoop path. I removed one and tried to restart hive. The error message was then the same but with the 2 following jars log4j-slf4j vs slf4j-log4j. So should I remove all the 4 jars used by Hadoop and hive and stored in their respective directories ?

Comment: They each have a specific purpose about how pipe logs in through the slj4j api and out again.  I would suggest reading the slf4j documentation, as this is a little bit cumbersome due to historic reasons.  You may want to add the complete list of jars in your deployment to your question.

Comment: I will add the list of jars. Would like to thank you man for taking the time. Will update with the list of jar as soon I will be back home

Comment: Hi Thorbjorn: sorry for my weak knowledge but how do you remove a jar from a classpath...?

Comment: @lucTiber You open the file explorer and remove the file. However, that might make things worse if something depends on that file

Comment: Oh... that’s it. I thought there was some Java ish magic... let si how it flies....

Comment: Thanks by the way onecricketeer

Comment: Hi Folks, removing the files make it only worst (from warming messages perspective) - here are the message I get (too many charachters so kept only what looks like most relevant):                                                    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil
...Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil

Comment: I am adding the following open question : how could it be possible I cannot have hive working on hadoop ... Am I missing something ... or worst (sorry this is me getting upset about 2 core bricks of the hadoop echo system cannot work at all )